# Сокеты. Передача структур данных через сокеты

Tags: java

Как можно передать через сокеты различные структуры данных типа ArrayList, массивы объектов и т.п?

Answer (score 3):

Самое простое - это воспользоваться парой из [ObjectOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html) и [ObjectInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html):

**Server.java**

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
        names.add("Jack");
        names.add("John");
        names.add("Jimm");

        try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(2121)) {
            try (Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                 ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())) {
                out.writeObject(names);
            } 
            catch (IOException exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
        catch (IOException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**Client.java**

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Client {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> names;
        try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 2121)) {
            try (ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream())) {
                try {
                    names = (List) in.readObject();
                    names.forEach(System.out::println);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException exc) {
                    exc.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (IOException exc) {
                exc.printStackTrace();
            }           
        } catch (UnknownHostException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException exc) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```